# Which algorithm is this?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis

I'm looking for someone who can tell me which algorithm this is and help me to clearify what the variable mean.

- $g_j$ : the shortest path length from $1$ to $j$
- $t_{i,j}$: the length from $i$ to $j$
- $\mathrm{SCS}$: successive set
- $S$: Start node, $G$: Goal node

\begin{align}
   &f_G = 0 \\
   &f_i = \infty, \forall i ≠ G \\
   &t_{i,j} = \infty, \forall (i, j) \notin T \\
   &t_{i,j} > 0 , \forall (i, j) \in T\\
   &T = \{1, 2, . . . , N − 1, N\}, \quad Ť = \{\emptyset\} \\
   &\text{Do while $T$ is not empty} \\
   &\qquad j^* = \arg\min_{j\in T} f_j \\
   &\qquad \text{for }i \in \mathrm{SCS}(j^*)\\
   &\qquad\qquad f_i  = \min \{f_i , t_{i,j}^* + f_j^*\}\\
   &\qquad \text{Remove $ j^*$ from T, add $j^* $ to Ť} \\
   &\text{Stop while }j^*= S
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Regarding your MathJax comment, see [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short reference.

Comment: Still bad but it's the best I can do with my limited time atm. Will check on it tomorrow. Thanks for the link

Comment: @何承䬠 Should "$f_i  = \min (f_i , t_{i,j}^* + f_j^*)$" be "$f_i  = \min (f_i , t_{i,j} + f_j^*)$", since $t_{i,j}^*$ is not introduced?

Comment: That exactly how I took it from my course material @Apass.Jack. Thats why I'm asking here X,D

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a [Dijkstra algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to me.

I see the algorithm begins at the "do while" line and everything before are the input for the algorithm. With your clue that G is the goal node, and $t_{i,j}$ are *lengths*, it is easy to see $f_i$ is the distance from $i$ to G as we know so far within the loop.

So the algorithm means the following:

- Every iteration, we find the node $j^*$ within T that has min distance to G
- Then we scan each of its neighbor $i$, update their distance to G

  - update rule: they reach G with traversing $j^*$ or without (i.e., the old $f_i$), so min of these two will be the new known min distance to G
- After this scan, all nodes that can possibly reach G via $j^*$ are updated. And we remove $j^*$ from T, meaning that in the future, any other node (not neighbor to $j^*$) to reach G via $j^*$ should only be via one of its neighbor $i$

Here the $t_{i,j}$ are positive, so that adding to $f_{j^*}$ can only increase the distance. And hence all $f_i$ will only be decreasing in each iteration. In this case, this algorithm is a dynamic programming by iteratively reducing the problem to a smaller set of nodes until a solution is found.

Comment: @Apass.Jack You're right. I overlooked.

Comment: Thanks alot. It finally makes sense